# How to force react not to re-render children, just receive a state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my situation:

```js
shortArray.map(data => (
  <div className={this.state.active === data.id ? "show" : "dontShow"}>
    {this.processAVeryLongArray()}
  </div>
))
```

I hope you get the idea. Just a state change happens, and `processAVeryLongArray` is independent from it. The only thing I need the state is to change the classname of an element, but the children doesn't change. By the way, it rerenders all children. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method?

Comment: React.memo: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Answer (score 2):

The ideal approach is to make the child components [Pure Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent). If the props to the child components are not changing, the Pure Components will not re-render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` lifecycle hook. You write logic to check the value of your properties and state, after checking you return true to re-render the component, else return false to deny re-rending of the component. Read more about them on their official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

or you could use `React.PureComponent` instead of `React.Component`, if you want React to handle re-rendering logic by comparing all old and new props and state values behind the curtain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

inside your child component to decide whether each of them should update or not.

[Here's](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) also some techniques, best practices and pitfals.